# how to convert number image to display the data of student

Tags: ocr

This system should record the attendance of a student by using OCR on a captured image from a devcice that using android. The details of the student will be displayed and recorded after the OCR processes the character (for example, a number to identify the students) in the captured image.

The steps: capture an number image using a any device using operating system android --> OCR recognizes the numbers in the image --> the numbers will be use to display the student's data and record his or her attendance for the day.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re asking about is called **OCR**, and it isn’t as simple as you might think. there is one [open-source](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) effort to do it.